# Paillier paper: Number Theoretic Lemma doesn't seem to work

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, modular-arithmetic, paillier

I'm reading [the original Paillier paper](http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/810/chp%253A10.1007%252F3-540-48910-X_16.pdf?originUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fchapter%2F10.1007%2F3-540-48910-X_16&token2=exp=1493060998~acl=%2Fstatic%2Fpdf%2F810%2Fchp%25253A10.1007%25252F3-540-48910-X_16.pdf%3ForiginUrl%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Flink.springer.com%252Fchapter%252F10.1007%252F3-540-48910-X_16*~hmac=aa6e7da3c8420d5ce97eda2e54bd0d662060df6fe606d4b67a3060650490ae13).

I've reached **Lemma 3**: If the order of $g$ is a nonzero multiple of $n$, then $\varepsilon_g(x,y) = g^x y^n \mod n^2$ is a bijection, where $x \in \mathbb{Z}_n$ and $y \in \mathbb{Z}_n^*$.

Take for example $n=6$, $n^2=36, \mathbb{Z}_6^* = \{1, 5\}$.

Let $g=5$. The order of $5$ modulo $36$ is $6$ (see [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=order+of+5+modulo+36)), which is a multiple of $6$, so $\varepsilon_g$ should be a bijection.

Let $(x_1, y_1) = (1, 1)$ and $(x_2, y_2) = (1, 5)$. Then:

- $y_1, y_2 \in \mathbb{Z}_6^*$ as required.
- $\varepsilon(x_1, y_1) = 5^1 \cdot 1^6 = 5$
- $\varepsilon(x_2, y_2) = 5^1 \cdot 5^6 = 5$ (assuming operations are modulo $36$.)

So... It's not a bijection. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer: This appears to be an error in the paper, but it's not a problem in practice.

The proof of Lemma 3 uses the following implication:

> Since $\gcd(\lambda,n)=1$, $x_2-x_1$ is necessarily a multiple of $n$. Consequently, $x_2-x_1=0\bmod n$ and $(y_2/y_1)^n=1\bmod n^2$, which leads to the unique solution $y_2/y_1=1$ over $\mathbb Z_n^\ast$.

As your example shows, the assertion $\gcd(\lambda,n)=1$ is wrong in general: $n=2\cdot 3$, hence $\lambda=(2-1)\cdot(3-1)=2$, and $\gcd(\lambda,n)=2\neq1$. Structurally, this becomes manifest in the fact that the ring $\mathbb Z/n^2$ contains nontrivial $n$th roots of unity — in your case the element $5$ — which voids the uniqueness claim.

It is not hard to prove that for $n=pq$ a product of two primes, this phenomenon occurs if and only if $p=2$ or $q=2kp+1$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$. <sub><sup>(Modulo reordering of $p$ and $q$.)</sup></sub>
The chance of this happening is negligible for any realistically-sized and randomly generated pair of primes $(p,q)$, hence this is not going to be an issue in practice.

Comment: Do you know if a proof that $(2, 3)$ and $(p, 2kp+1)$ are the only exceptions exists somewhere online?

Comment: Got the proof about $gcd(\lambda, n)$ from p492 of [this book](http://www.textbookunderground.com/buy_book_detail.asp?pf_id=11623922&gclid=CPuCiJ3bv9MCFZdWDQodQvYAzg) If we assume w.l.o.g. $q>p$, $\gcd(\lambda,n) = \gcd((p-1)(q-1), pq) > 1 \implies \gcd(p-1, p) > 1 $ OR $ \gcd(q-1, q) > 1$ (both impossible) OR $\gcd(p-1, q) > 1$ (also impossible since $q$ is prime, $q > p$) OR $\gcd(q-1, p) > 1$. So it must be the last  case: $q-1 = c p, c\in \mathbb{Z}$. We know $q$ is odd, so if $c$ is odd,  $p$ must be even, so $p=2$. Else $c = 2k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @danxinnoble A relevant link is [A Note on 'Non-secret Encryption'](http://cryptocellar.org/cesg/notense.pdf). It decribes RSA prehistory ($e=n$) and gives correct  conditions $(p-1,q)=(q-1,p)=1.$